# How Can I Schedule Periodical Task With Android WorkManager with 5 Mintes Interval

Tags: android, scheduled-tasks, android-workmanager

Greeting StackOverflow community!

In my Android app, I am trying to schedule a periodical task, that will be executed every 5 minutes. There are some requirements:

1. Should be independent of the app lifecycle
2. Should be restarted after the device reboot
3. Should be an exact 5 minutes interval

I check a lot of Google Docs and found, that WorkManager is the best choice for this case. I should say, that the task is sending some stats to the server. But the main problem is the minimum interval time for PeriodicWorkRequest equals 15 minutes

The question is: how can I setup 5 minutes interval for PeriodicWorkRequest, or there is a better solution? Maybe I should use older AlarmManager for this case? I am new in Android development and not sure, what solution will be better.

Hope for you and I will be glad to get any kind of help =)

Comment: Minimum time interval for WorkManager is 15 minutes . You can use alarm manager but google play will give warning if you are using too many alarm managers as it will stop device from sleeping . The best bet would be do use a foreground service and run the task

Comment: This has not been practical on Android for years, courtesy of things like Doze mode and app standby.

Comment: @ManoharReddy so the best bet is to run foreground service with notification and use delay for 5 minutes interval like this one: 
`void doSomeTask() { while(true) { delay(5 * 6000); /*do some work*/ }}`

Am I right?